# How to prevent a column in QTableWidget from being edited when dragging and dropping content

Tags: pyqt, qgis

I have a TableWidget with two columns where cells are non-editable. I want to lock the one column where insertion is disabled: i.e. when I'm doing drag and drop from other table no insertion should happen in that column. How to do that with PyQt?

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

```
from operator import xor
for i, item in enumerate(items_to_add, count_number_of_items):
           count_number_of_items += 1
           self.dialogClass.table_to_be_filled.setRowCount(count_number_of_items)
           item1 = QTableWidgetItem(item)
           item1.setFlags(xor(item1.flags(),QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable))
           self.dialogClass.table_to_be_filled.setItem(i, 0, item1)
```